# Jenkins-pipeline fail : No such DSL method 'androidLint' found among steps

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I get a failure for the stage 'Static analysis' during my jenkins-pipeline.

Here is my Jenkinsfile :

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Compile') {
      steps {
        // Compile the app and its dependencies
        sh './gradlew compileDebugSources'
      }
    }
    stage('Unit test') {
      steps {
        // Compile and run the unit tests for the app and its dependencies
        sh './gradlew testDebugUnitTest testDebugUnitTest'

        // Analyse the test results and update the build result as appropriate
        junit '**/TEST-*.xml'
      }
    }
    stage('Build APK') {
      steps {
        // Finish building and packaging the APK
        sh './gradlew assembleDebug'

        // Archive the APKs so that they can be downloaded from Jenkins
        archiveArtifacts '**/*.apk'
      }
    }
    stage('Static analysis') {
      steps {
        // Run Lint and analyse the results
        sh './gradlew lintDebug'
        androidLint pattern: '**/lint-results-*.xml'
      }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
      steps {
        // Build the app in release mode, and sign the APK using the environment variables
        sh './gradlew assembleRelease'

        // Archive the APKs so that they can be downloaded from Jenkins
        archiveArtifacts '**/*.apk'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the Console Output :

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Static analysis)
[Pipeline] sh
+ ./gradlew lintDebug
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:lintDebug
Wrote HTML report to file:///var/jenkins_home/workspace/Pushr_master/app/build/reports/lint-results-debug.html
Wrote XML report to file:///var/jenkins_home/workspace/Pushr_master/app/build/reports/lint-results-debug.xml

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 23s
14 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 13 up-to-date
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy)
Stage "Deploy" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline

GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'androidLint' found among steps [archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, compareVersions, deleteDir, dir, dockerFingerprintFrom, dockerFingerprintRun, echo, emailext, emailextrecipients, envVarsForTool, error, fileExists, findBuildScans, findFiles, getContext, git, input, isUnix, jiraComment, jiraIssueSelector, jiraSearch, junit, library, libraryResource, load, lock, mail, milestone, node, nodesByLabel, parallel, powershell, properties, publishChecks, publishHTML, publishIssues, pwd, pwsh, readCSV, readFile, readJSON, readManifest, readMavenPom, readProperties, readTrusted, readYaml, recordIssues, resolveScm, retry, scanForIssues, script, sh, sha1, sleep, stage, stash, step, tee, timeout, timestamps, tm, tool, touch, unarchive, unstable, unstash, unzip, validateDeclarativePipeline, waitUntil, warnError, withContext, withCredentials, withDockerContainer, withDockerRegistry, withDockerServer, withEnv, withGradle, wrap, writeCSV, writeFile, writeJSON, writeMavenPom, writeYaml, ws, zip] or symbols [PVSStudio, acuCobol, ajc, all, allBranchesSame, allOf, always, androidLintParser, ansibleLint, ant, antFromApache, antOutcome, antTarget, any, anyOf, apiToken, architecture, archiveArtifacts, armCc, artifactManager, authorizationMatrix, axivion, axivionSuite, batchFile, bitbucket, bitbucketBranchDiscovery, bitbucketForkDiscovery, bitbucketPublicRepoPullRequestFilter, bitbucketPullRequestDiscovery, bitbucketSshCheckout, bitbucketTagDiscovery, bitbucketTrustEveryone, bitbucketTrustNobody, bitbucketTrustProject, bitbucketTrustTeam, bitbucketWebhookConfiguration, bitbucketWebhookRegistration, booleanParam, branch, brokenBuildSuspects, brokenTestsSuspects, buckminster, buildButton, buildDiscarder, buildDiscarders, buildRetention, buildUser, buildingTag, cadence, cargo, caseInsensitive, caseSensitive, ccm, certificate, changeRequest, changelog, changeset, checkStyle, checkoutToSubdirectory, choice, choiceParam, clair, clang, clangAnalyzer, clangTidy, cleanWs, clock, cmake, codeAnalysis, codeNarc, command, coolflux, cpd, cppCheck, cppLint, credentials, cron, crumb, cssLint, culprits, defaultFolderConfiguration, defaultView, demand, detekt, developers, diabC, disableConcurrentBuilds, disableResume, docFx, docker, dockerCert, dockerLint, dockerServer, dockerTool, dockerfile, downstream, doxygen, drMemory, dscanner, dumb, dupFinder, durabilityHint, eclipse, email-ext, envVars, envVarsFilter, environment, equals, erlc, errorProne, esLint, excludeCategory, excludeFile, excludeMessage, excludeModule, excludeNamespace, excludePackage, excludeType, expression, file, fileParam, filePath, findBugs, fingerprint, fingerprints, flake8, flawfinder, flexSdk, frameOptions, freeStyle, freeStyleJob, fromDocker, fromScm, fromSource, fxcop, gcc, gcc3, gcc4, gendarme, ghsMulti, git, gitBranchDiscovery, gitHubBranchDiscovery, gitHubBranchHeadAuthority, gitHubExcludeArchivedRepositories, gitHubExcludePublicRepositories, gitHubForkDiscovery, gitHubPullRequestDiscovery, gitHubSshCheckout, gitHubTagDiscovery, gitHubTopicsFilter, gitHubTrustContributors, gitHubTrustEveryone, gitHubTrustNobody, gitHubTrustPermissions, gitTagDiscovery, github, githubPush, gnat, gnuFortran, goLint, goVet, gradle, groovyScript, hadoLint, headRegexFilter, headWildcardFilter, hyperlink, hyperlinkToModels, iar, iarCstat, ibLinter, ideaInspection, includeCategory, includeFile, includeMessage, includeModule, includeNamespace, includePackage, includeType, infer, inheriting, inheritingGlobal, installSource, intel, invalids, isRestartedRun, issues, java, javaDoc, javadoc, jcReport, jdk, jdkInstaller, jgit, jgitapache, jnlp, jobBuildDiscarder, jobName, jsHint, jsLint, junitParser, junitTestResultStorage, klocWork, kotlin, ktLint, label, lastDuration, lastFailure, lastGrantedAuthorities, lastStable, lastSuccess, legacy, legacySCM, list, local, location, logRotator, loggedInUsersCanDoAnything, mailer, masterBuild, maven, maven3Mojos, mavenConsole, mavenErrors, mavenMojos, mavenWarnings, metrowerksCodeWarrior, mineRepository, modelsim, modernSCM, msBuild, myPy, myView, nagFortran, namedBranchesDifferent, newContainerPerStage, node, nodeProperties, nonInheriting, none, not, overrideIndexTriggers, paneStatus, parallelsAlwaysFailFast, parameters, password, pattern, pcLint, pep8, perforce, perlCritic, permanent, php, phpCodeSniffer, phpStan, pipeline-model, pipeline-model-docker, pipelineTriggers, pit, plainText, plugin, pmdParser, pollSCM, prefast, preserveStashes, projectNamingStrategy, protoLint, proxy, pruneTags, puppetLint, pyDocStyle, pyLint, qacSourceCodeAnalyser, queueItemAuthenticator, quietPeriod, rateLimit, rateLimitBuilds, recipients, recordIssues, requestor, resharperInspectCode, resourceRoot, retainOnlyVariables, rfLint, robocopy, ruboCop, run, runParam, sSHLauncher, scala, schedule, scmRetryCount, scriptApproval, scriptApprovalLink, search, security, shell, simian, simpleBuildDiscarder, skipDefaultCheckout, skipStagesAfterUnstable, slave, sonarQube, sourceRegexFilter, sourceWildcardFilter, sphinxBuild, spotBugs, ssh, sshPublicKey, sshUserPrivateKey, standard, status, string, stringParam, styleCop, sunC, suppressAutomaticTriggering, swapSpace, swiftLint, tag, tagList, taskScanner, taskingVx, teamSlugFilter, text, textParam, tiCss, timestamper, timestamperConfig, timezone, tmpSpace, tnsdl, toolLocation, triggeredBy, tsLint, unsecured, untrusted, upstream, upstreamDevelopers, userSeed, usernameColonPassword, usernamePassword, viewsTabBar, warningsParsers, warningsPlugin, weather, withAnt, x509ClientCert, xlc, xmlLint, yamlLint, yuiCompressor, zfs, zip, zptLint] or globals [currentBuild, docker, env, params, pipeline, scm]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:216)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor475.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:163)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:161)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:165)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:135)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:32)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.delegateAndExecute(ModelInterpreter.groovy:137)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.executeSingleStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:661)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.catchRequiredContextForNode(ModelInterpreter.groovy:395)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.catchRequiredContextForNode(ModelInterpreter.groovy:393)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.executeSingleStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:660)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:288)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.toolsBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:544)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.toolsBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:543)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withEnvBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:443)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withEnvBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:442)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:275)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withCredentialsBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:481)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withCredentialsBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:480)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:274)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.inDeclarativeAgent(ModelInterpreter.groovy:586)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.inDeclarativeAgent(ModelInterpreter.groovy:585)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:272)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.stageInput(ModelInterpreter.groovy:356)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.stageInput(ModelInterpreter.groovy:355)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:261)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.inWrappers(ModelInterpreter.groovy:613)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.inWrappers(ModelInterpreter.groovy:612)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:259)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withEnvBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:443)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withEnvBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:442)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:254)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor178.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatch(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:55)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.item(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor190.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:136)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I am not sure why I get "No such DSL method 'androidLint' found among steps".

I thought it's a jenkins-plugin problem, since Android Lint Plugin seems deprecated, I can't access to the link : https://plugins.jenkins.io/android-lint/

I installed the plugin : Warnings Next Generation => https://plugins.jenkins.io/warnings-ng/
that seems to contain Android Lint Plugin, and yet, I still get the error : No such DSL method 'androidLint'...

Does someone have any idea why the stage('Static analysis') fail ? Is it a missing plugin ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigation, it seems "androidLint" is not supported by "Warnings Next Generation Plugin", and has been replaced by "androidLintParser"

the correct step with Warning Next Generation plugin is :

```
stage('Static analysis') {
  steps {
    // Run Lint and analyse the results
    sh './gradlew lintDebug'
    androidLintParser pattern: '**/lint-results-*.xml'
  }
}
```